# Word VBA code has Run-Time Error 1004 Every other time it is run

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have created the simple code below to export a table from a word document to an excel file. I am looking to apply this concept to a larger project. The code runs fine the initial time but has Run - Time Error 1004 every other time. After the debug is cancelled it runs again fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error reads Method 'Cells' of object'_Global failed

```
Sub tableexport()

Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim Word As Document
Set Word = Documents("Comps extraction from reports")
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim RowWord As Long
Dim ColWord As Long
Dim oWB As Workbook
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\chris\Desktop\TABLE EXPORT.xlsx")
oExcel.Visible = True

RowWord = Word.Tables(1).Rows.Count
ColWord = Word.Tables(1).Columns.Count

With Word.Tables(1)
    'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
    For i = 1 To RowWord
        For j = 1 To ColWord
            Cells(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(i, j).Range.Text)
        Next j
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is *word* VBA then `Application` would be `Word` rather than `Excel`, so wouldn't you need something to qualify the line that is throwing the error so that VBA knows what `Cells` and `WorksheetFunction` refers to? I am surprised that this code runs at all.

Comment: You should save and close the workbook after each run, and quit oExcel. You should also fully qualify *which* excel instance you're using e.g oWB.sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j)...

Comment: @Winterknell The fact that they are setting `Visible` to true suggests that they want the workbook open after the sub has run. You do point out a possible issue in that if they run the sub a second time before saving and closing then they will be trying to open and already open workbook in a second instance of Excel.

Comment: Good point, and probably correct, although when I encounter RTEs in my own code I will often do the same (set it visible) so that I don't accumulate invisible Excel instances that I have to kill in Task Manager.

Comment: @Winterknell Perhaps you could turn your comment into an answer. I wouldn't be surprised if the fact that the code doesn't clean up after itself is a major part of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Word VBA, you need to properly qualify any reference to the Excel object model. In particular, the line

```
Cells(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(i, j).Range.Text)
```

should be

```
oWb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, j) = oExcel.WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(i, j).Range.Text)
```

Also, I suspect that

```
Dim oWB As Workbook
```

Should be

```
Dim oWB As Object
```

Word VBA doesn't know about WorkBook Objects (though perhaps you have included a reference?)

Comment: Using the fully qualified Excel instance should be enough. If they have set a Reference to the Excel object  model they can use its methods, although again, they should ensure each use is properly qualified.

Comment: Qualifying indeed does work. This now works perfectly. Thanks very much for the help!